# Крон, добавленный через php скрипт не запускается

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

Добавил крон в файл */etc/crontab* с помощью метода *file_put_contents*. Крон добавляется в файл, но не запускается. Если открыть файл и сохранить вручную, крон срабатывает. Можете подсказать в чем может быть ошибка?
Для работы с кронами через скрипт использовал класс из статьи http://www.kavoir.com/2011/10/php-crontab-class-to-add-and-remove-cron-jobs.html.

Немного модифицировал метод *saveJobs* для сохранения крона в файл *crontab*.

```
static public function saveJobs($jobs = array()) {
    $output = file_put_contents('/etc/crontab', self::arrayToString($jobs));
    return $output;
}
```

Команда добавления крона

```
Crontab::addJob("*/1 * * * * root php -f /var/www/get_all_clients_data_db.php ");
```

Файл */etc/crontab* после добавления крона

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
*/1 * * * * root php -f /var/www/get_all_clients_data_db.php
```

Выполнение команд

```
sudo service cron restart
sudo service cron reload
```

не помогло.

Comment: Думаю проблема в правах доступа, сверьте перед сохранением и после права на файл

Comment: Если крон запущен от одного юзера, а php под другим работает

Comment: Для проверки кронов указал 766 права для файла /etc/crontab. Если открыть файл с добавленным кроном в nano и пересохранить его, крон выполняется.

Comment: Из под какого юзера открываете в редакторе `nano`?

Comment: @korytoff Файл редактируеся под `root`.

Comment: Мой опыт телепатии говорит, что проблема в правах доступа. Если из под рута все работает. Смотрите системные логи

Comment: всё-таки лучше изменять не `/etc/crontab`, а специально созданный для ваших целей файл в `/etc/cron.d`. если, конечно, используемый вами *crond* поддерживает такую возможность (в актуальных версиях популярных дистрибутивов по умолчанию — поддерживает).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ошибку. При добавлении крона через скрипт в системных логах `/var/log/syslog` возникала следующая ошибка.

```
/usr/sbin/cron[8391]: (*system*) ERROR (Missing newline before EOF, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

При использовании скрипта в файл /etc/crontab не добавлялась новая строка в конец файла, поэтому возникала ошибка. После добавления в строку с кроном `"\n"` крон выполнился.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать `sudo crontab -e` и в редакторе не писать код вообще. Т.е.

```
0 4 * * *       cp file1 file2
```

не факт, что выполнится правильно. А вот

```
0 4 * * *       /opt/sh/my-cp-script.sh
```

очень даже выполнится.
Сам скрипт следует начинать с [шебанга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_%28Unix%29). Получится нечто:

```
#! /bin/bash
cp /full/path/to/file1 /full/path/to/file2
```