# Как настроить wget cron на plesk 12?

Tags: linux, debian, cron

Работал весь день, чтобы настроить cron задачу на Plesk.
Для тестирования cron задачи использовал [этот метод](http://www.instantcms.ru/blogs/stranyi-blog/kak-proverit-rabotaet-li-zadacha-cron.html) и создал два документа: `my_cron.php` и пустой `my_cron.txt`

Код `my_cron.php`:

```
<?php 
  $fd = fopen("my_cron.txt","a"); 
  fwrite($fd, "Обращение к файлу - ".date("d.m.Y H:i")."\r\n"); 
  fclose($fd); 
?>
```

Затем зашел в панель `Plesk` → `Websites & Domains` → `Scheduled Tasks`
и добавил задание:

```
2 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "http://site.com/testcron/my_cron.php"
```

К сожалению, задача не запускается, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Сервер linux debian, права к файлам txt и php - 777.

Cron работает, проверял его путем создания такого крон задания:

```
echo "Test email"
```

**Upd:** обнаружил, что при установке на первый домен (всего используется 2 домена в plesk: один находится в директории /site1.com/httpdocs , второй находится в директории /site1.com/site.com ) при загрузке файла my_cron.php в директорию /site1.com/httpdocs/my_cron.php и запуске команды `wget -q "http://site1.com/mycron.php" -O /dev/null` все работает прекрасно единственная разница возникает в ip адресах. При проверке обычного запроса `wget http://site1.com/my_cron.php` выходит ip адрес сервера, при запросе `wget http://site.com/my_cron.php` выходит внешний ip адрес.

**Upd2:** после изменений в файле /etc/hosts ping двух домен через ssh показывает одинаковый ip. И запросы wget и curl работают, но крон задачи не запускаются.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487530/191416 - попробуй так.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin cron работает для команды отправки эмэйла, для команды wget не работает

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, полная директория файла my_cron.txt имеет вид: /var/www/vhosts/site.com/site2.com/testcron/my_cron.txt

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на запрос `wget -O - http://site.com/testcron/my_cron.php`
Получил такой ответ:
`--2016-03-08 11:26:07-- http://site.com/testcron/my_cron.php
Resolving site.com (site.com)... ip.address.here
Connecting to site.com (site.com)|ip.address.here|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-03-08 11:26:07 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Comment: @Darklez, *ERROR 404: Not Found* — вот и разбирайтесь с этой ошибкой, а не с придуманной вами «задача не запускается».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin дайте пожалуйста направление как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: @Darklez, создайте вопрос с заголовком типа «не запускается php-скрипт», в котором опишите ситуацию: что и где создано, как настроен http-сервер и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы заключается в добавление дополнительного домена и `ip` в файл `/etc/hosts`